# Populate a blank bitmap with pixels from another bitmap in Android?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I want to create a blank bitmap, which I will conditionally fill with Rects of pixels obtained from another bitmap that holds a resource. Is it possible to do that? How would I go about doing something like that?

I only want to draw the bitmap once it is ready to be drawn.

Right now I'm using Canvas to draw the bitmap using Rect segments, but I don't need it to be drawn until it is ready.

Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: No need to apologize, just wanted to help; a better question gives  better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bitmap other = ...;
//create a blank bitmap
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(other.getWidth(),
                      other.getHeight(), other.getConfig());

//copy some pixels from 'other'
int x=14,y=45,width=23,height=56;
int [] pixels = new int[width * height];
other.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, x, y, width, height);
newBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more, that what will this chunk of code do? and please share some screenshots to get the exact result